# Как в Delphi создать класс в отдельном файле?

Tags: delphi

Можно ли в Delphi создать класс и поместить его в отдельный файл, подобно тому, как это делается в C#?

Comment: да, можно. Просто создайте отдельный юнит и там разместите свой класс. В принципе, не должно возникнуть никаких особых проблем

Comment: Обратная последовательность: создаёте юнит и в нем - класс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, можно. Более того, в некоторых случаях это даже рекомендуется делать именно так.

Особенность работы Delphi с private-членами класса состоит в том, что к private могут обращаться не только методы класса, а любой код в том же файле.

Порядок действий: Создать unit, описать в нем свой класс, указать свой unit в uses тех файлов, которые должны использовать ваш класс.